# Error get data from pgadmin to c# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, pgadmin

This is my code for selecting data from C# to pgadmin function:

```
private void button_load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            DGV_customers.DataSource = null;
            //load all data from table customers
            conn.Open();
            sql = "select * from customers_select()";
            cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            DGV_customers.DataSource = dt;
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "FAIL!!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            conn.Close();
        }
}
```

My function in pgadmin (postgresql):

```
create function customers_select()
returns table
(
    _member_id int,
    _name character,
    _phone_number character,
    _address character,
    _height character,
    _weight character,
    _age character
)
as
$$
begin
    select member_id, name, phone_number, address, height, weight, age;
end
$$
language plpgsql
```

This shows an error:

> 42703: column "member_id" does not exist

Comment: Does the error go away if instead you write `select _member_id, _name, _phone_number, _address, _height, _weight, _age` ?

Comment: yes, i add return query before select, but i got other problem |||

code :
conn.Open();
sql = @"select * from st_insert(:_member_id,:_name,:_phone:_number,:_address,:_height,:_weight,:_age)";
cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_member_id", textBox_member_id.Text);


Show Error : 42601: syntax error at or near ":"

Comment: I recommend reformulating the question for addressing you new problem. That way, the code in your comment, properly formatted, can be easily understood by me and others and we can help you. More so if you include details of the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button_save_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            customers_form.DGV_customers.DataSource = null;
            conn.Open();
            sql = @"select * from st_insert(:_member_id,:_name,:_phone:_number,:_address,:_height,:_weight,:_age)";
            cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

            //customers_form DGV_customers = new customers_form();
            customers_form.DGV_customers.DataSource = dt;
            customers_form.DGV_customers.Rows.Add(textBox_member_id.Text, textBox_name.Text, textBox_phone_number.Text, textBox_address.Text, textBox_height.Text, textBox_weight.Text, textBox_age.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_member_id", textBox_member_id.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_name", textBox_name.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_phone_number", textBox_phone_number.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_address", textBox_address.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_height", textBox_height.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_weight", textBox_weight.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_age", textBox_age.Text);

            if((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
            {
                conn.Close();
                //this.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Success insert a new Customers", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                button_save_insert.PerformClick();

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: "+ex.Message, "INSERT FAIL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Function for insert in pgadmin :

```
    create function st_insert
(
    _name character,
    _phone_number character,
    _address character,
    _height character,
    _weight character,
    _age integer
)returns int as
$$
begin
    insert into customers
    (
        name,
        phone_number,
        address,
        height,
        weight,
        age
    )values
    (
        _name,
        _phone_number,
        _address,
        _height,
        _weight,
        _age
    );
    if found then
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
    end if;
end
$$
language plpgsql
```

Show error in visual studio c#

Error : 42601: syntax error at or near ":"